# Fadeout Cursor in JavaFX After Few Seconds Delay

Tags: javafx, cursor, javafx-8, fadeout

On my application(Media Player), when application is in fullscreen mode, I am fading out the top bar and bottom bar. I also wants to fade out the cursor after few seconds delay. I tried `FadeTransition`, but it take only `Node` as parameter.

I also tried using thread.

```
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                scene.setCursor(Cursor.NONE);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

Here I just wanted to hide the cursor after two seconds delay. It works, but also hang my application for two seconds which I don't expect.

In which way I can fade out the cursor after two seconds delay?

Comment: About the opacity it maybe be possible creating 10 different icons of the same cursor with different opacity.Then very fast change them from one to other through for example 1 second,using `ImageCursor`.Cause i am curious about that ,maybe i do it and post the code.:)

Comment: Here you are: https://github.com/goxr3plus/JFXCustomCursor

Comment: Thanks, I have seen your project, it is really nice :)

Comment: Glad to hear!      .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is making the UI hang because you are making a blocking call (`Thread.sleep(...)`) on the FX Application Thread. If you want to do it that way, you should block on a background thread and schedule the change of the cursor on the FX Application Thread when the pause is complete.

An easier way, though, is just to use a [`PauseTransition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html):

```
PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(2));
pause.setOnFinished(e -> scene.setCursor(Cursor.NONE));
pause.play();
```

You can use this as well to make the cursor reappear on when the user does something, and disappear again after 2 seconds:

```
scene.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.ANY, e -> {
    scene.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
    pause.playFromStart();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the 2nd part added extra advantage for me. 
In addition, can you help me about fading out the cursor. I would like if it will disappear gradually.

Comment: I don't see any way to do that. `Cursor` doesn't have an `opacity` property, and I don't think there's a way to create a `Cursor` out of a `Node`.

Comment: @James_D I am using a `WritableImage` along with a `PixelWriter` to make the image transparent but instead of that i get a black rectangle..Why that happens?`WritableImage` doesn't support transparent?Help appreciated..